# Ubuntu. Если dns-nameservers установлен, то при перезагрузке система останавливается

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vmware, windows-server-2012

Конфигурация:

- Vmware 12.5.7
- Guest OS -> Ubuntu 16.04
- Host OS -> Windows Server 2012 R2

Настроил статический IP адрес.
Если dns прописан в `/etc/network/interfaces`, то при перезагрузке/выключении система останавливается на строке:
`[ OK ] Stopped target Network is Online.`

[image: Stopped target Network is Online].

(https://image.prntscr.com/image/UnrjZX8wRHKZXlSdEhITYg.png).

Если днс не прописан, то всё хорошо.
В логах записей нет, чисто.

В чём может быть проблема?

Файл `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto ens33
    iface ens33 inet static
        address 213.159.X.X
        netmask 255.255.254.0
        gateway 213.159.X.X
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

======================

Решение - https://www.sunlix.de/weblog/mysql-service-unter-ubuntu-15.10-wird-nicht-richtig-beendet/

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. // приложите к вопросу и содержимое всех файлов `/etc/network/interfaces*`

Comment: на картинке приведены текстовые сообщения (угу, оксюморон получается ввиду вашего нежелания приводить текстовую информацию в виде текстовой информации) о завершении работы. сообщения о том, почему именно работа завершается, в вопросе отсутствуют. приведите полный лог неудачной загрузки (ввиду того, что вы используете новомодный systemd, которым подменили уже половину операционной системы, это [не так-то просто](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159221/110559)).

Comment: ах, да. у вас опечатка: `dns-nameservers`, а не `dns-nameserver`

Comment: я пробовал и dns-nameservers и dns-nameserver, везде так же. Сделать картинку текстом не получается, не выделяется и не копируется нигде

Comment: а если убрать dns какая  следующая строка в логе после "OK stopped target network is online" будет?

Comment: какая следующая не знаю, строки проходят быстро и сразу перезагрузка

Comment: удалось поймать следующую строку, только как Mysql связан с dns не понимаю
(https://image.prntscr.com/image/UnrjZX8wRHKZXlSdEhITYg.png)

Comment: Решение - https://www.sunlix.de/weblog/mysql-service-unter-ubuntu-15.10-wird-nicht-richtig-beendet/